# pickerView and action Button

Tags: ios, swift, action

I'm faced with a problem where when I try to do an action on a specific row from my pickerView.

Ex, I have multiple items in pickerView and back in the core data I have counter attribute so what I need to do is once I select a specific item from the pickerView and click on button that counter attribute should increased by one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var MEDARRAY = [NSManagedObject]()
var Counter:NSInteger?
var thecounte:Int?

@IBOutlet weak var thepicker: UIPickerView!


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return MEDARRAY.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return String(describing: MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medName")!)
}
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
    let NumDay = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger
    let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as? NSInteger
    Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as? NSInteger)!
    TotalDose.text = String(NumDay! * NumMed!)
    RemainDose.text = String(Int(TotalDose.text!)! - Counter!)

}
//here is the button should increase the counter 
    @IBAction func Taken(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let Appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = Appdelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newCounter = Counter! + 1
    do{
        // how to specified the did selected row in here to update the counter value for that row
        self.MEDARRAY[newCounter].setValue(newCounter, forKey: "takenCounter")
        try context?.save()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

How can I specify the did selected row for the picker view so I can use it in the button function?

Comment: you mean you want the selected row from picker in button action ?

Comment: exactly so i can modified a value of that object been selected in core data

Answer (score 0):

If you create another variable called `selectedObject` like so:

```
var selectedObject = NSManagedObject()
```

And update it in your `pickerViewDidSelectRow` method:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
    let NumDay = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNumDay") as? NSInteger
    let NumMed = self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "medNum") as? NSInteger
    Counter = (self.MEDARRAY[row].value(forKey: "takenCounter") as? NSInteger)!

    //updates whenever a new row is selected
    selectedObject = self.MEDARRAY[row]

    TotalDose.text = String(NumDay! * NumMed!)
    RemainDose.text = String(Int(TotalDose.text!)! - Counter!)
}
```

Then you can call this when your button is pressed, and it will give you the most recently selected row, so that you can increment its "count" field.

```
@IBAction func Taken(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let Appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = Appdelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newCounter = Counter! + 1
    do{
        //initialize index variable
        let index = MEDARRAY.indexOf(selectedObject)

        //use index in your MEDARRAY call
        self.MEDARRAY[index].setValue(newCounter, forKey: "takenCounter")
        try context?.save()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error "Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type (of: [NSMANAGEDOBJECT]"

Comment: I just checked, and it works for me in playground. Are you sure you set selectedObject to type NSManagedObject and not [NSManagedObject]?

Comment: @ammari No problem, don't forget to mark the accepted answer so that future visitors can be helped better :) Thanks!

Comment: benjamin the app still carshing once i spin the pickerview , i update the code can you check it please :S

Comment: I don't see any updated code. Also, what error is it giving you that is causing the crash?

Comment: the crash came once i spin the pickerView and error is error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'

Comment: selectedObject = self.MEDARRAY[row]